# How to use URLs like '/update/:id' as KendoUI datasource?

Tags: rest, kendo-ui, kendo-datasource, kendo-mvvm

I read the documentation but found nothing related to setting parameters in dataSource urls. Is it possible to achieve that?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The `url`s defined in the `DataSource.transport` might be a function. This function receives (for `update`) as first argument the data being updated (the model) and returns the string that should be used as URL.

Composing the URL for what you want to do is:

```
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: function () {
                return 'read';
            }
        },
        update: {
            url : function (item) {
                return 'update/' + item.id;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Tested. Correct answer and very concise. Thanks. :)

Comment: Indeed, this works great but only if `batch=false` in your datasource (which is by default). When you enable batch operations, the `item` argument will be a collection of models - which'll not map to a single RESTful service.

Comment: Can you explain this bit more. I did not get, how I pass the 'item' to this function.

Comment: If you're having a problem where item.id is undefined, try adding `id: "id"` to your Model.

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be vague on 'item.'

Just note that 'item' is an object.  In fact anything passed in to read has to be an object, that's what Kendo expects.  If you pass anything else into read, like a string, it will convert it into an object which isn't what you want.  So, the solution is as follows:

```
    _viewModel: kendo.observable({
        items: new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: function (args) {
                        var urlParm = '?take=' + 1 + '&skip=0&page=1&pageSize=' + 1;
                        return CGI_ISD._base + 'api/executionsummary/executiondetails/' + args.msgId + urlParm;
                    },
                    dataType: "json"
                },
            },
            schema: {
                data: function (response) {
                    return response.AggregateData.Data;
                }
            }
        }),
    }),
    _reload: function (msgId) {
        this._viewModel.items.read({msgId: msgId});
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

**Short answer**:

Nope.

**Long answer**:

Parameters are passed either inline with the `url` parameter of the transport object...

```
var id = 'abc123';

var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  transport: {
    read: {
      url: 'api/employees?id=' + id
    }
  }
});
```

...or they are passed in the `data` parameter of the transport object.

```
var id = 'abc123';

var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  transport: {
    read: {
      url: 'api/employees',
      data: {
        id: id;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

or

```
var id = 'abc123';

var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  transport: {
    read: {
      url: 'api/employees',
      data: function () {
        return { id : id };
      }
    }
  }
});
```